# x86 Assembly Programming, using movzx and movsx for variables properly

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I am working on homework assignment for assembly programming class. Here is the assignment

> Implement the following expression in assembly language:
>
> - BX = -val1 + 20 – (val2 + val3)
>
>   - Assume that val1, val2, and val3 are 8-bit integer variables
>   - Initialize val1 with 5, val2 with 8, and val3 with -4
>   - You are only allowed to use 16-bit registers to hold intermediate results, whenever needed.
>   - Use movzx, movsx or neg instructions whenever needed.
>   - Use the debugger to verify your answer.

Here is my code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
.data
val1 sbyte 0        ;intialize val1
val2 sbyte 0        ;intialize val2
val3 sbyte 0        ;intialize val3
result sword 0      ;intialize result
.code
main proc
mov val1,5      ;val1 = 5
mov val2,8      ;val2 = 8
mov val3,-4     ;val3 = -4

mov ax,0
mov bx,0
mov cx,0
mov dx,0


movzx dx,val1       ;dx = val1
neg dx              ;dx = -val1
add dx,20           ;dx = -val1 + 20

movzx ax,val2       ;ax = val2
neg ax              ;ax = -val2 
movzx cx,val3       ;cx = val3
add ax,cx           ;ax = -val2 + val3
add dx,ax           ;dx = -val1 + 20 -val2 + val3

mov result,dx       ;result = dx
mov bx,dx           ;bx = result, = -val1 + 20 -val2 + val3 
invoke ExitProcess,0
    main endp
end main
```

But when i use debugger to check register and see the value of bx its not returning the correct integer value i want, and i believe i should use the movsx command somewhere in the code, but i am sure how to because the variables i declare are 8-bit and we are only allowed to use 16-bit immediate storage

Comment: All your `val`s seem to be signed, use `movsx` everywhere. Easy.

Comment: the bit size does not matter?

Comment: Think about the significance of the parentheses in the problem spesification.

Comment: @LuciusAnderson the bit size matters most importantly. If you have 8 bit source values, they can be either `int8_t` or `uint8_t` - both are exactly 8 bit "big" = one byte, and in memory they are indistinguishable (both being 8 bits and nothing else), it's about the code which is interpreting them, the code decides if the value is signed or unsigned. Signed 8 bits are interpreted usually as -128..+127 values, unsigned 8 bits are usually interpreted as 0..+255 values (although you can write code which will treat those 8 bits also as 1340..1850 values, using only even number (1340, 1342, ...).

Comment: As the task description says the val1/2/3 are 8 bit integers, that means signed values. For convenience and simple 16b math, just use `movsx` into 16b register everywhere, to convert from -128..+127 range to -32768..+32767 range (possible range, the value will not change, so right after `movsx` from `int8_t` you will have still -128..+127 at most, but now extended to `int16_t`).